# ¿Por qué un hook personalizado no actualiza todas las propiedades de un objeto?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, componentes, usestate

Tengo este hook que cree, que se ejecuta cada que se hace un submit en un formulario. El problema es que cuando se hace la validación solo actualiza la propiedad valPass y no actualiza el valName. Ya verifique el operador ternario y funciona perfecto, lo unico esque no actualiza en valName
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. No pegues el código como imagen, dale a [edit](/edit) y modifica la pregunta siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El Hook de `useState` reconoce solo una de tus solicitudes. Recuerda que cuando se cambia el `state` del componente en `React`, se re-renderiza y por lo tanto se sobreescriben las solicitudes y solo toma una: la última. Esto tiene que ver como el Hook funciona sumado al comportamiento extremo que tiene `for` en `Javascript`, ya que el las iteraciones en `Javascript` son "instantáneas" a diferencia de `Python`.

```javascript
const handleValidations = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const {userTest, passTest } = expresions;

  const controlVar = {};

  for (const key in formData){
    if(key === 'password')
      controlVar.valPass = (passTest.test(formData[key])) ? false : true;

    if(key === 'nameUser')
      controlVar.valName = (userTest.test(formData[key])) ? false : true;
  }
  setFormData({...formData, ...controlVar})
}
```

Coméntanos cómo te va!

Comment: Hola! ya pude solucionarlo, lo que hice fue crear un objeto temporal y es el que utilizo en el for, cuando se termina el for  le paso el objeto temporal para cambiar el satate.

Comment: ¡Coincidimos! Es la solución que te propuse. Que bien que la descubriste y que bueno que quede aquí para otros Reacfans.